# Programmatically query deployed Jetty 8 applications

Tags: jetty

Is there a way I can query the list of deployed applications in a Jetty 8 server in code? For instance, can I inject the DeploymentManager and query it?

Answer (score 0):

From a handler, you should have a reference to the Server object so you should be able to dig around for it from there, or just pass in reference to it when you create it and are knitting things together.  Handlers are simple to write and wire up.  Look at the StatisticsHandler usage as an example if you like.

From a servlet that is not really appropriate since there is a webapp classloader and webapps are classloader isolated for a reason.